# Java = Getter/Setter = Does this increase "object size" at runtime and accesstime (CPU Cycles?)

Tags: java, performance

i need to write an ajax applicatoin, where on the server side (implemented in java) millions of small objects will be created and held in memory. normally I use the beanstyle (with getter / setter) for any objects.

My question: Does it make a difference (in regard to memory usage and CPU Time for access) at runtime, having getter/setter methods for an instanciated object versus not having them and directly accessing the fields/members?  For example if having getter/setter makes an object bigger for 5bytes per method and instance, then this would dramatically add up in total with millions ob objects. The same with accessing a getter vers directly accesing the member/variable in regard to cpu cycles.

```
public String myvartoaccess;

vs

private String myvartoaccces;
public String getMyvartoaccess();
```

Thanks very much!
Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and setters do not affect memory usage.  The method implementations of getter/setter are stored with the `Class` of which there is only one (in a given classloader).  The instances only store the state of the object.

Regarding performance, I doubt it would be significantly slower to call simple getter/setters.  I would definitely first implement with the getters and setters, and then if you find it is too slow, you could potentially do away with them.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil after all.

Comment: A bit late coming to this : but this "premature optimization being the root of all evil" is misleading. I'd argue that premature usage of methods to access simple fields is premature complication.  Ignoring efficiency at an early design stage is bad since the redesign and effort later on might be exorbitant. Its one of those sayings thrown around that sound good but have little practical value : the worst being the old chestnut about better to do it right the first time than using a debugger later.... The programmer who doesn't need a debugger is very special indeed on modern code bases.

Answer (score 7):

A getter and setter will add a small amount to the size of the **class**; however, the size of the individual **objects** will not be affected.  So whether you have a single object or ten thousand, the memory cost of the method will be added exactly once.

As for the CPU overhead, there will be a small overhead; however, this should be optimized and negligible.

Comment: Yes, lacqui is correct. Real value comes with the various libraries and tools that access this fields using this getter/setter.

Comment: The JVM will most likely inline simple getters, thus there will not be any CPU overhead.

Answer (score 4):

No difference. JVM will optimize the getter as if it's a field read.

Answer (score 0):

Getter and setter methods shouldn't make the objects larger, just the class that represents those objects. It's unlikely going to matter to your performance to have getter and setter methods, especially since the JVM should optimize that out. If you're concerned about performance or memory then you should load test and profile your application. Most likely you'll find a problem elsewhere, I really wouldn't worry too much about this part.